# QtCUrl post doesn´t work anymore (Linux nok...windows ok)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, curl, linux-mint

I have been running this function since last year (Linux and Windows) within my program.

Now I need to implement a new function and my new build is no longer running.

I have other CUrl functions using POST and the results are the same: nok, but my GET functions are ok.

I have another computer (with Mint 19) where this program is running smoothly, but on my computer (using Mint 19, too) the compilation is fine, but it starts curl.exec (I'm using `Qtcurl` library and inside has a call to `curl_easy_perform`) and no longer returns.

I have this package installed: libcurl4-openssl-dev

It's okay to compile my program (Linux and Windows). This program is running on Windows.

My problem is just new builds in Mint19.

What is missing to install?

```
QUrl url("https://pos-api.ifood.com.br/oauth/token");
QUrlQuery q;
q.addQueryItem("client_id", id); 
q.addQueryItem("client_secret", secret); 
q.addQueryItem("grant_type","password"); 
q.addQueryItem("username",user); 
q.addQueryItem("password",password); 

url.setQuery(q);

QtCUrl::Options opt;
opt[CURLOPT_URL] = url;
opt[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
opt[CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION] = true;
opt[CURLOPT_FAILONERROR] = true;


opt[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER]= false;  // windows

QStringList headers;
headers
    << "cache-control: no-cache"
    << "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
opt[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = headers;
val = cUrl.exec(opt);  // PROBLEM HERE!!!!

if (cUrl.lastError().isOk()) {

    bool ok;
    // json is a QString containing the JSON data
    QtJson::JsonObject result = QtJson::parse(val, ok).toMap();
    token=result["access_token"].toString();


    return token;
}
else {
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed all my methods.

The first funcion is a POST with query.

```
    QString iFood_getToken2(QString token, int *expira, QString id, QString secret, QString user, QString password, QString host){
    if(host!=hostname || !ifood_ativo){
        qDebug() << "iFood_getToken2 saindo...";
        return "";
    }

    if(*expira>IFOOD_TASK){
        *expira-=IFOOD_TASK;
       // qDebug() << "expira " << *expira;
        return token;   // token válido
    }

    QUrl url("https://pos-api.ifood.com.br/oauth/token");

    QUrlQuery q;
    q.addQueryItem("client_id", id); 
    q.addQueryItem("client_secret", secret); 
    q.addQueryItem("grant_type","password"); 
    q.addQueryItem("username",user); 
    q.addQueryItem("password",password); 
    url.setQuery(q);

    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
    request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::CacheLoadControlAttribute, QVariant(int(QNetworkRequest::AlwaysNetwork)));

    QJsonObject json;

    QNetworkAccessManager nam;

    QNetworkReply *reply = nam.post(request, QJsonDocument(json).toJson());

    while (!reply->isFinished())
    {
        qApp->processEvents();
    }

    QByteArray response_data = reply->readAll();
    QJsonDocument jsonr = QJsonDocument::fromJson(response_data);
    reply->deleteLater();

    //qDebug() << "ifoodtoken2 " << jsonr["access_token"].toString();

    return jsonr["access_token"].toString();
}
```

I did implement these new functions:

There is a new implementation for a GET and PATCH

So, from now on I dont need to use CUrl library anymore

```
QJsonDocument networkGet(QString strUrl, QString token){
    QUrl url(strUrl);

    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::CacheLoadControlAttribute, QVariant(int(QNetworkRequest::AlwaysNetwork)));

    QString headerData = "bearer " + token;
    request.setRawHeader("Authorization", headerData.toLocal8Bit());

    QJsonObject json;

    QNetworkAccessManager nam;

    QNetworkReply *reply = nam.get(request);

    while (!reply->isFinished())
    {
        qApp->processEvents();
    }

    QByteArray response_data = reply->readAll();
    QJsonDocument json_response = QJsonDocument::fromJson(response_data);
    reply->deleteLater();

    //qDebug() << "networkGet " << json_response << reply->errorString() << headerData ;

    return json_response;

}

int networkPatch(QString strUrl, QString token, QJsonDocument json){
    QUrl url(strUrl);

    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::CacheLoadControlAttribute, QVariant(int(QNetworkRequest::AlwaysNetwork)));
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");

    QString headerData = "bearer " + token;
    request.setRawHeader("Authorization", headerData.toLocal8Bit());

    QNetworkAccessManager nam;

    QByteArray * _b_arr = new QByteArray (QString(json.toJson()).toLatin1());
    QBuffer *_qbf_upload =new QBuffer (_b_arr);
    QNetworkReply *reply = nam.sendCustomRequest(request,"PATCH",_qbf_upload);

    while (!reply->isFinished())
    {
        qApp->processEvents();
    }

    QByteArray response_data = reply->readAll();
    QJsonDocument json_response = QJsonDocument::fromJson(response_data);
    reply->deleteLater();

    qDebug() << "networkPatch " << reply->error() << json_response << reply->errorString() << headerData ;

    return reply->error();

}
```